# unable to run j2me app in emulator

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish

i am trying to run j2me app in emulator using eclipse but when i run the app i am getting following error

```
Error installing IMlet. See logs for details.
```

i tried to explore different thread but could not get definite answer.it asks to download IMlet Suite but i didnt find a place from where i can download it.

i am using windows 8 64bit machine

[image]

i am pretty new to this so please guide accordingly.

when i m trying to run following command

```
C:\WTK22\bin>emulator.bat
```

it shows following error

```
C:\WTK22\bin>C:\PROGRA~2\Java\JRE18~1.0_3\bin\java.exe -Dkvem.home=C:\WTK22 -Dja
va.library.path=C:\WTK22/bin -Dsun.java2d.ddlock=true -Dsun.java2d.gdiblit=false
 -cp C:\WTK22/wtklib/kenv.zip;C:\WTK22/wtklib/ktools.zip;C:\WTK22/wtklib/customj
mf.jar com.sun.kvem.environment.EmulatorWrapper
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: KeepAliveConnection
not initialized
        at com.sun.kvem.environment.KeepAliveConnection.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.kvem.environment.EmulatorWrapper.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: does WTK emulator works for you if launched standalone?

Comment: well if i go into my eclipse workspace and double click over `.jad` file it opens up in a emulator